# how can i replace some things in my array?

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I need to format a date in my array - but the date in the array isn't saved as a `datetime` in a database or something like this.. I've got the dates from my server with cut them out.

So I need to work with `preg_replace` or with `str_replace`

What I've tried so far using `str_replace`:

```
    $reverse_date = str_replace( '[', '' ,$reverse_date);
    $reverse_date = str_replace( ']', '' ,$reverse_date);
    $reverse_date = str_replace( '/', '.' ,$reverse_date);
```

but I don't want to use three lines for this.

If I `print_r` this, I will get : `12.Oct.2015:01:10:43 +0200`

before it was looking like this : `[12/Oct/2015:00:37:29 +0200]`

so this is okay ! But I still don't want to use three lines for this, but I don't understand the `preg_replace` syntax

I want the following output :

```
12.Oct.2015(space)01:10:43 +0200
```

Comment: Is it a string or an array

Comment: its an array ! but i just need the first data of the array so $reverse_date[1]

Comment: Post your array structure

Comment: here are 2 dates of my array : ,"[12\/Oct\/2015:01:09:51 +0200]","[12\/Oct\/2015:01:08:50 +0200]",

Comment: Check my answer instead..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have said you were getting a date from an array within the following format

```
[12/Oct/2015:00:37:29 +0200]
```

So instead of using `str_replace` or `preg_replace` you can simply use `DateTime::createFromFormat` function of PHP like as

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("[d/M/Y:H:i:s P]","[12/Oct/2015:00:37:29 +0200]");
echo $date->format('d.M.Y H:i:s P');//12.Oct.2015 00:37:29 +02:00
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/468162)

Comment: I'm getting this error message:  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DateTime' not found

by this:                               $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("[d/M/Y:H:i:s P]","$reverse_date[1]");
        echo $date->format('d.M.Y H:i:s P');

Comment: Are you using Laravel

Comment: You are in a namespace, use `\DateTime::create...`

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_parse` to disassemble the date and combine the parts to form your needed result:

```
[40] boris> $date_array = date_parse(" [12/Oct/2015:00:37:29 +0200] ");
// array(
//   'year' => 2015,
//   'month' => 10,
//   'day' => 12,
//   'hour' => 0,
//   'minute' => 37,
//   'second' => 29,
//   'fraction' => 0,
//   'warning_count' => 0,
//   'warnings' => array(
// 
//   ),
//   'error_count' => 2,
//   'errors' => array(
//     0 => 'Unexpected character',
//     27 => 'Unexpected character'
//   ),
//   'is_localtime' => true,
//   'zone_type' => 1,
//   'zone' => -120,
//   'is_dst' => false
// )
```

You don't have the month as abbreviated string, but that is trivial to add via an associative array (`array(1 => 'Jan', ..., 12 => 'Dec')`), and you are on the safe side concerning the date-parsing stuff and future changes in your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out how to do it with preg_replace in one line, however I like the Uchiha answer with the date format more - even that he is not using the regex, this is probably the best way to go.

```
echo preg_replace(['~(?<=\d{4}:\d{2}):~', '~[\[]~', '~[\]]~', '~[\/]~g'],[' ', '', '', '.'],'[12/Oct/2015:00:37:29 +0200]');
```

**12.Oct.2015:00 37:29 +0200**

Comment: it wouldn't replace the first colon with a space

Comment: colon with a space ? where

Comment: *"I want the following output :12.Oct.2015(space)01:10:43 +0200"* - last 2 lines in the question

Comment: oh ok i see what you mean

Comment: have a look at this one - fixed